# how do I fire a workflow weekly on its own with out a record being created or edited

Tags: infopath

I have a workflow which adds a new record to list. I want that workflow to be fired weekly on its own with out a item being created or edited.

Please help me on how this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Console Application in Visual Studio which calls the Workflow Web Service of your list. Once this is done you can create a scheduled task in your server or local machine and set it to run every week.

Using the Workflow Web Service you can call the `StartWorkflow` method to trigger your workflow. You can find an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcworkflow.workflow.startworkflow%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You might be talking about a list workflow here.

You can do below:

1. Create a timer job that runs once a week & triggers the workflow for some item in the list.
   **Harder option**
2. Create a timer job that runs once a week & just calls listitem.Update() so that the workflow gets triggered automatically.
   **Easier option**

For these kind of requirements,

> Its better to COPY the logic from your workflow & PASTE it into the
>   timer job

(of cource you have to edit it as per the timer job context).

Comment: For the benefit of people who don't have your approach down pat, can you please explain what a timer job is, what is required to create it and how to create one? Consider that there might be people here that know nothing about Visual Studio. How can this be done with the browser UI or SharePoint Designer? If it ***does*** require VS, please indicate that and don't take it as a given that everybody here does .NET. "Create a timer job" means nothing to SharePoint Power Users, who can make SharePoint sit up and beg using just the browser. So, please explain in more detail.

Comment: Yes teylyn, one should probably add all the steps. But there is a word called "please" in the actual question, it tells how desperate the person is for answer (idea). So its better to put it out there so that he/she can proceed further by googling about "how to create timer job" & what not. Since stack is a community, others can/will join in. I believe answers should point out the requestor in a direction & not only about spoon feeding, which takes hell lot of time (given one doesn't any other thing to do)

Answer (score 0):

We recently released Workflow Scheduler for SharePoint Online in Office 365. I guess it is what you are looking for.

- [SharePoint Store](https://plumsail365.sharepoint.com/sites/kh/_layouts/15/storefront.aspx?vw=AppDetailsView,app=WA104313851,clg=0#vw=AppDetailsView,app=WA104313851,clg=0)
- [Product site](http://plumsail.com/workflow-scheduler/)

Note: This product is paid, but quite cheap. I'm developer of this product.